# Цикл ожидания в ходе выполнения CGI скрипта

Tags: python-3.x, cgi

В CGI скрипте на python 3.4 надо открыть url и после этого организовать цикл ожидания действий пользователя в течение 5 минут, проверяя каждые 10 секунд. 
Код такой:

```
print("Content-type: text/html")
print()
# открываем страницу для действий пользователя
print('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.example.ru" />')
# организуем цикл на 5 минут ожидания действий пользователя с проверкой 
# ожидаемого события каждые 10 секунд
time_waiting = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
while datetime.datetime.now() < time_waiting:
    do_some_procedure() # проверяем наступило ли ожидаемое событие
    time.sleep(10)
```

Проблема: при наличии цикла с оператором `time.sleep()`, URL в браузере не открывается, пока не закончится цикл ожидания, хотя цикл ожидания находится в скрипте ПОСЛЕ. Если цикл ожидания убрать то страница откроется сразу. Как открыть url в CGi скрипте, если после него должен идти `time.sleep()`?

Comment: О последствиях действия пользователя на данном url я смотрю в 5 минутном цикле каждые 10 сек  на отдельном сервере, а не на этом конкретном url. Информация с браузера меня не интересует. Все изменения отображаются в другом месте (БД). Но url не отображается пользователю если следом идет оператор time.sleep().

Comment: не относится к вопросу: если не секрет, чем вызвано использование cgi? (вместо, wsgi, используя к примеру, [bottle.py](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/), flask, etc библиотеки?)

Answer (score 1):

Пока страница целиком не загружена (пока цикл работает в вашем случае) refresh не произойдёт.

Чтобы выполнить задачу в фоне, а пользователя перенаправить на другую страницу, не дожидаясь пока цикл закончится:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import run, DEVNULL, STDOUT
run('batch', input=b'/path/to/check-updates', stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=STDOUT)
print("Status: 303 See Other")
print("Location: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6122957/4279")
print()  # end of headers
```

где `/path/to/check-updates` содержит ваш цикл с `time.sleep()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import contextlib
import os
import time

with open('/tmp/check-updates', 'a', 1) as f, contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):
    deadline = time.monotonic() + 300  # +5 minutes
    while time.monotonic() < deadline:
        print(os.getpid(), time.asctime())
        time.sleep(10)
```

Вместо `batch` можно сетевой запрос к используемой очереди задач отправить или специализированному демону, который проверками занимается.